# Most recommended framework to develop rich yet easy-deployable webapps

Tags: ruby-on-rails, django, spring, gwt, web-applications

im getting into webapp's programmin Im very confused about lots of frameworks available, each one based in different languages. Ive found lots of them (and just test drive some of them) I have experience with Java, PHP, Javascript, CSS, HTML, Python (but never tried django), C/C++ languages

By now, the best I got with is Ruby On Rails. I don't have much knowledge of the ruby language but it does look pretty similar to python, i mean, it looks like an easy language. So, learning Ruby to use it with rails justifies it?

Ive found frameworks such as:

Spring (Java)
Django (Python)
GWT (Java)
Rails (Ruby)
These looks the more advanced and mature frameworks out there, so, what are your experience about developing webapps with different frameworks? What are the advantages/disadvantages of each one? (Or any other you would like to mention.) and good resources or books you'll recommend.

Ive read that java based ones are far more complicated and tedious, and Rails seems to be a nice middleground between complexity and effectiveness. Also GWT (Google Web Toolkit) seems nice to develop the UI as It gives you sets of widgets to use.

Im looking for a framework with rich user interfaces, to develop desktop-like apps for the web...

Any comments, ideas, suggestion would be appreciated!

Excuse my bad english! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Im looking for a framework with rich user interfaces, to develop
>   desktop-like apps for the web...

If that's the case [GWT](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/) would be a good choice.

The rest of the frameworks you mention (and the majority of those labeled as "web frameworks") focus more on the backend, and don't provide many tools for the kind of frontend development you want. You need to combine them with other frontend frameworks to achieve that.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to go for standard "server-side" java, I could recommend JSF with [primefaces](http://www.primefaces.org).  It's a bit hard to get it first, but the community is wide and books/documentation are highly available.  Primefaces as a rich set of widgets (take a look at the showcase) and it is very active.

Whatevver framework you will choose, I greatly suggest you to learn and use [JQuery](http://jquery.com/) for your javascript needs.  Personnaly jquery is now a must in all my web applications.
You will always find plugins and widgets ready to use based on jquery.

You should take a look at [jquery-ui](http://jqueryui.com/).  It is a set of javascript widgets and utilities based on jquery.

Wish you good learning, and hope this will help :)